# Split String by backslash in JavaScript (JS)

Tags: javascript

var stringName = "Hello 1\2 check";

Hi i have string
and i want to split by the backslash. Please, can anyone suggest how i can handle this
I have tried with backslash, regex, replace, split method and unicode of backslash but none of method is use for me

Comment: The string `"Hello 1\2 check"` does not contain a backslash and is invalid in strict mode. Did you mean `"Hello 1\\2 check"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
var x = String.raw`Hello 1\2 check`.split('\\').join('\\\\')
y = x.split('\\\\')
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining your string, you should define it as:

```
var stringName = "Hello 1\\2 check";
```

Then, you can do

```
var myList = stringName.split("\\"); // ['Hello 1', '2 check']
```

Backslash is used for escaping characters and it can also escape another backslash.

```js
var stringName = "Hello 1\\2 check";
console.log(stringName.split("\\"));
```